# How to solve "This branch has conflicts that must be resolved" using Rebase

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have a PR on github but have the following issue on my branch `features` that says:

```
This branch has conflicts that must be resolved
```

My company solely uses rebase. How would I solve this using rebase?

My steps are:

1. Make another branch of `features` as backup
2. checkout master
3. pull master
4. checkout `features`
5. run git rebase master

Fix conflicts. Is this process correct? If so do I have to do a force push after?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `git rebase -i origin/master` from your features branch and follow-through to rebase. You should be familiar with the rebasing menu.

Answer (score 0):

Your process is correct. And yes, you must force push after.